# How to publish Google Spreadsheet extension on the Chrome web store?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, chrome-web-store

I'm interested in writing an extension for Google Spreadsheet that makes use of the spreadsheet's UI extending capabilities. If I'm not mistaken the only possible way to create such a program is to make it a container-bound script. Meaning it can only be published to the Spreadsheet script gallery. This is unfortunate since I would like to publish and maybe sell this script and, make it widely available to Google Spreadsheet users. I was thinking that the Chrome Web Store would be ideal for these kinds of things, but it's not possible to publish container bound scripts on it (only web apps can be published on it).

So, I'm looking for a solution to this problem. I've thought of a solution myself that might work: Create a web app and publish it on the Chrome store. The web app is actually a library that a container-bound script depends upon. Is this even possible? The container-bound script is stored in the gallery. Can you disallow users from using your script in the gallery if the haven't installed the web app?

To summarize, I have a few questions:

- Can container bound scripts use Chrome Web Store web apps as libraries and also require a user to have installed/bought the app?
- What are the other ways for creating and publishing Google Spreadsheet extensions?

Comment: By Chrome web app, do you mean Chrome extensions?
Communication between chrome extension and Apps Script may not be simple, 
you could try by using DOM APIs in extension by to enter contents in a dummy sheet's cell, and then on Spreadsheet you can write onEdit() triggers. And similarly, you can bind DOM click/MutationObserver events to listen for change in Spreadsheet content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add-ons have been introduced to allow you to extend Google Docs and Google Sheets. These can be published on the Chrome Store.

see this quick start write up https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs